# how to place images into sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, html, web-services, jquery

I have written the following code to place the image path into sql server 2005 but its not working is their any alternate way to place images into sql server from clientside application.

example.html

```
<form id="addresslistingform" name="addresslistingform">
<fieldset id="fieldset1">
  <legend>Address for listing</legend> Zipcode:<br />
  <input size="30" type="text" id="zipcode" /><br />
  Street No:<br />
  <input size="30" type="text" id="addstreetno" class="number" name=
  "streetno" /><br />
  Street Name:<br />
  <input size="30" type="text" id="addstreetname" class="required" name=
  "streetname" /><br />
  Upload a couple of pictures:<br />
  <input size="30" type="file" id="addpicture" /><br />
</fieldset><input id="Addresslisting" type="image" src="images/Submit.png" align=
"left" />
</form>
```

example.js

```
 $("#Addresslisting").click(function () {
    var zipcode = ($("#addzipcode").val());
    var streetno = ($("#addstreetno").val());
    var streetname = ($("#addstreetname").val());
    var image = ($("#addpicture").val());
    var submitaddress = "{\"zipcode\":\"" + zipcode + "\",\"streetnumber\":\"" + streetno + "\",\"streetname\":\"" + streetname + "\",\"streetname\":\"" + streetname + "\",\"Imagelocation\":\"" + image + "\"}";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/exampleproject/Afterlogin.asmx/addresslisting",
        data: submitaddress,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: ajaxSucceed,
        dataType: "json",
        failure: ajaxFailed
    });
});
```

asmx webservices file

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public bool addresslisting(string zipcode, string streetnumber, string streetname,  string Imagelocation)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "";
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand();//declaring a new command
        sqlcom.CommandText = "insert into Address_Listing(Zip_Code,Street_Number,Street_Name,Image_Location) values ('" + zipcode + "','" + streetnumber + "','" + streetname + "',  '" + Imagelocation + "')"; //query for inserting data into contact table
        sqlcom.Connection = con;//connecting to database

        try
        {
            int success = sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            if (success > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            con.Close();
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the code you've posted - except for that fact you haven't bothered trying to debug yourself.  Please provide more info, exactly what 'is not working'?

Comment: Please let me know when and where this goes live; I'd like to try out the SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recommend storing images in SQL server, what you really should do is store the path to the image on your server in the SQL server.

Also p.campbell wasn't very helpful but very correct.  Your database is going to get hacked with the code you currently have.  You need to use SQL Parameters to prevent malicious SQL code from being injected.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx